# Karate match error: match failed: EQUALS $ | match failed: EQUALS

Tags: java, api, karate

I want to match a value in the column of the database using Karate for my API Automation.

I have done as below .

```
* def test= db.readRow("select * from testdb.col xyz where xyz.id = '")
```

next i get the value from the Database and match . The Value is in the form of a JSON value

> ```
> match test.someCol == {"JSonValue1": null, "JSonvalue2": null, "JSonvalue3": "b", "JSonvalue4": "a"}
> ```

When i run this , i get as below.

> ```
>  com.intuit.karate.KarateException: match failed: EQUALS
>    data types don't match (OTHER:MAP)
>      {"JSonValue1":null,"JSonValue2":null,"JSonValue3": "b", "JSonValue4": "a"}
>      {"JSonValue1":null,"JSonValue2":null,"JSonValue3":"b","JSonValue4":"a"}
> ```

I tried doing as:

> ```
> match test.someCol == karate.toString({"JSonValue1": null,"JSonvalue2": null,"JSonvalue3": "b","JSonvalue4": "a"}).
> ```

I got the below error :

> ```
> com.intuit.karate.KarateException: match failed: EQUALS
> data types don't match (OTHER:STRING)
> ```

Can someone help me please.

Comment: same problem as in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72731813/143475 - so the rules are simple. ensure everything is a java map. clearly whatever you returned from `db.readRow()` is not. and you can try `karate.fromString()` if you have a JSON string. if still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: i tried the "fromString" as well. it did not work. same issue.

Comment: I have nothing to add to my comment above. you have to re-look at the code you have for the `db.readRow()` this is not related to karate